# How does simultaneous combat work in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization V multiplayer, all the turns are simultaneous. What if, for example, on the very same turn one ranged unit fires upon a scout. On that very same turn the scout moves out of range.

Since the turns are simultaneous, what happens? Does the scout move without getting hit? Does the scout get hit and then move? Does it get hit and not move at all?

I can't find anywhere that actually specifies the rules for how combat is actually resolved with simultaneous turns. I realized it's actually quite important since in a recent multiplayer game I gave my units a bunch of orders that were, apparently, never executed. And at the beginning of the next turn I was completely wiped out.

Comment: As far as I've heard, at that point Civ V moves over into the realm of RTS, i.e. who-clicks-first-wins. I don't have any first-hand multiplayer experience with it so far yet though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Simultaneous" in this context doesn't mean everything happens at the same time, it means **every player takes their turn at the same time** (not sure about the AIs...), pretty much with the rules you'd expect in single player - if you tell a scout to move, it will move straight away.

So, in your scout sceanrio two things could happen:

1. **You move first**: Your scout moves away, the archers cannot fire because they are out of range. The archers are still free to move as usual.
2. **They move first**: The archers bombard your scout. Afterwards you can still move your scout (assuming it is still alive).

I've not played a lot of multiplayer, and haven't had a really intensive war yet, but I imagine there's a little bit of "fastest trigger gets an advantage" in situations...

Comment: The only reason I'm hesitant about his is because of the multiplayer game I just played. On my screen my opponents entire army all moved at once instead of one unit at a time.

Comment: @Apreche Ah, well if you give an order to move to a location out of range the unit will move what it can instantly, and then "queue" the additional movement until the end of the following turn - much like in single player where units with standing orders wait until you hit "next turn" and then all move together.

Comment: Oh, so you are saying he queued up his entire attack on the previous turn, then pushed next turn, so I had no chance?

Comment: @Apreche Well, *possibly* ... As said haven't played any really war-intensive MP games yet, so don't know if that's a valid tactic for a mass attack :). But, queuing orders *does* work exactly as per single player. I guess a further question here is **what happens if two queued units try to interact?** Hmm...